# How to run multiple Tornado processes/threads/frontends?

Tags: python, deployment, tornado

In the tornado documentation they show how they can have a very large through-put from [4 frontends](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation#performance). I'd like to run an app in the same way, and would like to have the frontends running as daemon processes managed with an init.d script*.

I'm fairly new to Python so don't really know where to start. Currently I'm starting the Tornado server manually in the terminal, passing in a new port number each time.

I've tried using the [python-daemon package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) in conjunction with the [lockfile package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lockfile) but the lockfiles that are created don't have the process ids in them and I can't see how to then kill the processes gracefully later on.

I don't really know where to go from here, and the Tornado docs leave a large chunk out regarding deployment.

<sub>* If there's a better way to manage the processes so that they can be monitored and managed as a group then please let me know.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).  It's great for managing multiple daemon processes.  You configure your applications in the supervisord.conf file and supervisord itself is launched from an init.d script.

Comment: http://www.jeremybowers.com/blog/4/tornado-web-framework-production-django-and-nginx/ has some good notes about deployment

Answer (score 1):

I can vouch for Supervisor too. We have been using tornado in production with 4 instances using supervisor and it is working uber smooth